# How do I get the costumes for FF13 and FF13-2 save files?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

I'm on Xbox360 for FF13: Lightning Returns. My save files are in the cloud for FF13 and FF13-2. My LR save file is also using the cloud storage. When/where/how do I get the 13 and 13-2 costumes? They aren't in the store when I picked up my free Cloud and Yuna costumes? Am I missing something?

Comment: I have the PS3 version, and had no problems acquiring them.  Do you have local copies of your save files?  I don't think the game can check the cloud for them, so you'll need to keep them on the console.  Not sure if it'll find them now that you've started the game, though.

Comment: Hm, it might be because I played FF13 and FF13-2 on another xbox (and moved the saves to the cloud storage). I'll try moving them locally to the xbox and see if they come up.

Comment: Its out for you already? That is so unfair! I have to wait til friday. ;-)

Comment: @Chris US release dates are typically Tuesday's while European releases are typically Fridays.

Comment: @Reafexus: Ah, I had noticed they were often different. Hadn't yet twigged that they were always(/usually) on set days. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to download the content from my cloud storage to my xbox.

I put in the discs for FF13 and FF13-2 and let it sync the cloud storage down. I then inserted Lightning Returns and my costumes were then available from the rewards store.

Comment: For anybody else confused it doesn't actually tell you specifically why you have these items, they just turn up. Also they are slightly confusingly in the "Outerworld Rewards" section. You can tell if you have the rewards by checking the garbs which are "Guadrian Corps" for FFXIII I think and "Knight of Etro" for FFXIII-2.